# Align Arrow graphic in the center and touching the bottom of the above bar

Tags: html, css

What's the best way to align my arrow graphic in the middle and also touching the bottom of the bar above?

Right now it's aligned to the left and there is space between the top bar and the arrow.

See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/Z7dZR/26/

Here's my HTML

```
<!-- Start Form -->
<div class="wrapper-twocol">
<div class="twocol_row">
<div class="twocol_cell1">
<div class="form-header">Watch Video</div>
    <div class="form-arrow"><img src="https://www.google.com/help/hc/images/sites_icon_arrow_down_small.gif" width="11" height="12"></div>
<img src="http://www.real.com/resources/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/stream-video1.jpg" width="386" height="279">
    </div>

<div class="twocol_cell2">
<div class="form-header">Watch Video</div>
    <div class="form-arrow"><img src="https://www.google.com/help/hc/images/sites_icon_arrow_down_small.gif" width="11" height="12"></div>
<img src="http://www.real.com/resources/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/stream-video1.jpg" width="386" height="279">

</div>
</div>
<!-- End Form -->
```

Here's my CSS:

```
/* 2 Column  */
.wrapper-twocol {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 20px 0 37px 0;
}

    .twocol_row {
    height:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    }

    .twocol_cell1, .twocol_cell2 {
        height:100%;
        width:47%;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:normal;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-left: 6%;
    }
        .twocol_cell1{
            margin-left: 0;
        }

.form-header {
    background:#939598;
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'SegoeRegular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;

}

.form-arrow {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: setting the image to display:block will remove the space between the header and the graphic. Other people suggested negative margins, but that isn't necessary and will give you mixed results depending on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you styling slightly. Your div is the entire width of it's parent so you just need to center align that divs contents.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Z7dZR/27/

```
.form-arrow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Should be margin-top: -3px;

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following solution.
First, wrap arrows within a wrapper-div:

```
 <div class="wrapper arrowWrapper"> 
    <div class="form-arrow">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/help/hc/images/sites_icon_arrow_down_small.gif" width="11" height="12">
   </div>
</div>
```

Second, apply following CSS:

```
.arrowWrapper {
    width:209px; /*It's the width of the buttons calculated by the developer tools*/
}

.form-arrow {
    margin:-3px auto 0 auto;
    width:11px; /*width of the arrow*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css only (removing the arrow image and its wrappers from the markup)
using the ::after selector. That's how you will prevent repeating of the  tag and the wrappers.

```
.form-header::after{
  content: url('https://www.google.com/help/hc/images/sites_icon_arrow_down_small.gif');
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom:-18px;
}
```

Here is the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7H5ea/1/